# Creating an Infragistics Edit Template using code

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, infragistics

We currently use Infragistics grid and we don't bind our datasets until run time, and then setup the grid settings in code.  This seems a bit long winded, but its the way our senior developer wants it done.

I would like to look into using the edit template and I was wondering if there was a way of auto generating an edit template from what is in the grid using c# code.  I've seen that if we bind at design time infra does a good job of creating the basic template.  Is this possible in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial on building templates in code that you can follow.  It's in the Infragistics documentation under the Using WebDataGrid section.  Here's the link http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2009.1/CLR3.5/html/WebDataGrid_Using_the_Template_Collection.html

If you need more help with this, you can always contact Infragistics support directly (http://www.infragistics.com/gethelp)